# How can i cast my interface object to my current object

Tags: vb.net, casting

I have following interface and class

```
Public Interface IMyInterface
    Sub GenericImplementation()
End Interface

Public Class MyClass
    Implements IMyInterface

    Public Sub GenericImplementation() implements IMyInterface.GenericImplementation
        'doing some stuff
    end Sub

    Public Sub DoRefresh()
        'doing some stuff
    End Sub
End Class
```

Now i have some code where i want to check if my object passed as interface is of the concrete type `MyClass` and then perform `DoRefresh()`

```
Public Sub TestMethod(testObject As IMyInterface)
    Dim test = TryCast(testObject, MyClass)
    If test IsNot Nothing Then
        test.DoRefresh()
    End If
End Sub
```

When i am debugging the code i can see clearly the my instance of the interface is a ´MyClass´.  But when i TryCast this it return nothing.

Comment: Check your imports. Are you sure that `MyClass` in the `TryCast` is the same class as the one that you've shown? Could you have picked up a different class with the same name?

Comment: exactly the same.., breaking my head here

Comment: Try doing a `Directcast` to see what error you get.

Comment: Just tried this. If i perform a directcast there is no exception, the return value is still nothing. When i perform a directcast with an other implementation of this interface it throws an exception...

Comment: see what `testObject.GetType.AssemblyQualifiedName` returns

Comment: Are you sure `testObject` is not nothing to begin with?

Comment: It seems the problem is indeed located elsewhere. Figuring that ouit now. testObject is returned from a property. Hovering over the property displays an object but it is returning nothing at all.. thnx for the help